# AngularJS Post data to PHP - trying to get property of non-object

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, post

I've been trying to post data from AngularJS to a PHP script and I'm having a little problem.

```
$scope.submitRecipe = function () {
    $http({
        url: "../assets/php/scripts/create-recipe.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            "recipeName" : $scope.recipeName
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        alert(response.data);
    });
}
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

echo $request->recipeName;
?>
```

When I submit (call the function submitRecipe()) it does return the recipeName but it then continues to my PHP Script and I get the error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in..

Any help and pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think that you were sending JSON …?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($_POST);` and checked what it gives you? You can also try `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));`. That should show you if you get form data or json.

Comment: You should start by printing the content of `$request` using `echo print_r($request, true)`. That echoed response will go back to AngularJS and you will see if the data survived the round-trip.

Comment: @asiby It alerts me what I expect, but then it continues to the script and nothing is displayed.

Comment: Where are you expecting it to be displayed? Other than the alert (which you say works), you're not doing anything to display the response.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I tried `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));` and it returns  `string(0) ""`

Comment: @Patrick Q I’m trying to keep the data and access it from my script, but when the form submits, after it has alerted and it takes me to my script, the data is NULL. I tried var_dump(request) and it just returns NULL.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `json_decode` returned `null`, causing this line to throw the error.

```php
echo $request->recipeName;
```

Check that the data return by

```php
json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))
```

is infact not `null` and the `Content-Type` is `application/json`

Comment: Running `var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));` returns `string(0) ""`. Like the data is wiped when it continues to the script.